# Making a library available only to a specific function

Tags: javascript

I am using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) to produce some charts.

Unfortunately this library does not have all the charts I want.

However,
I found a [fork of this library](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/) that implements the rest of the charts I need but they are missing features.

> I cannot regularly use both libraries because they conflict with each
>   other. Is it possible to have one library inaccessible globally but
>   accessible from only a certain function?

E.g:

```
//This function to interact only with Chart.js
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
        bezierCurve: false, pointDotRadius : 10
    });

//But this to interact only with ChartNew.js

        var myStackedBarChart = new Chart(ctx).StackedBar(data, options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Chart.js` is nicely contained, avoiding creating any global symbols other than `Chart` and even providing a jQuery-style `noConflict` where it releases the previous value of `Chart` if you need it to.

The fork, sadly, spews globals all over the place.

So you can do this by including the fork first, then including `Chart.js`, and doing this:

```
var RealChart = Chart.noConflict();
```

At that point, `Chart` refers to the fork, and `RealChart` refers to `Chart.js`.

You will, unfortunately, have the legion of globals that the fork creates. You might consider editing the file to contain them (see `Chart.js` for how).

Comment: This honestly made my day.